# Vaadin 10 and springboot - How to package a jar?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, vaadin10

The question is simple, but I spent the last 2 days trying to deploy my app. And so far it doesn't.

I have a single CSS file for my style, and when I execute the jar, CSS is not found (404) or the jar won't package.

As stated here: [Spring Boot Executable jar structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517324/spring-boot-executable-jar-structure)
"Do not use the src/main/webapp folder if your application will be packaged as a jar"
and
"You should place your static resources in src/main/resources instead."

so put the CSS here:
src/main/resources/styles.css

In Vaadin documentation (which is very pour on how to package...) I import the CSS like this:

```
@StyleSheet("styles.css")
```

Source : https://vaadin.com/docs/v11/flow/importing-dependencies/tutorial-include-css.html

Then I package my project:

```
 mvn clean package -Pproduction
```

I get this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:11.0.0:package-for-production (default) on project importparcoursup: Execution default of goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:11.0.0:package-for-production failed: An import that ends with 'styles.css' cannot be resolved: the corresponding file 'C:\Workspace\lasteclipeandjava10\parcoursup\target\frontend\styles.css' was not found.
> [ERROR] Double check the corresponding import and verify the following:
> [ERROR] * the import string is correct
> [ERROR] * the file imported is either present in 'frontend://' directory of the project or in one of the project WebJar dependencies or in one of the regular jar dependencies
> [ERROR] * if the file is present in one of the regular jar dependencies, it should be located in `META-INF/resources/frontend` directory in the jar

Can someone provide a simple example of a 'springboot + Vaadin10' app packaged as a jar with static resources inside ?

I tried so many configurations (put the CSS in META-INF, include webapp resources in the maven build process...) but after 2 days, I still can't deploy my app on the server!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## finally the solution

css has to be here:

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/frontend/styles.css
```

then declared as:

```
@StyleSheet("frontend://styles.css")
```

Comment: As an FYI, if you have .html files they need to be in this folder as well.

Answer (score 1):

This could be helpful too even though I still miss an example:

> Vaadin 10 makes some changes to the way it loads static resources,
>   such as application templates, custom styles and any additional
>   JavaScript files. The gist of it is that such files should be put in
>   src/main/webapp/frontend/ when building a .war file and
>   src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/frontend/ when building a .jar
>   file.

Link to Vaadin Dokumentation: [Vaadin 10 and static resources](https://vaadin.com/blog/vaadin-10-and-static-resources)