# Access JSP file Inside Fat Jar

Tags: spring-boot, maven-plugin

I have spring boot app which creates fat jar and the exploded version of the fat as below,

/META-INF/resources/index.jsp as per the below,

[Spring Boot Executable jar structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517324/spring-boot-executable-jar-structure)

i tried to access the prefix in application.properties,

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/resources/ - No luck
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /META-INF/resources/  - No luck
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /resources/ - No luck
```

So what could be the correct prefix for this one? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows :

## ApplicationConfigurerAdapter.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApplicationConfigurerAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }    
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/web-resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/").setCachePeriod(300);
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Debendra. For me it's works if i run in eclipse the but if i create executable jar no luck.

Comment: Did you have taken embedded tomcat ??Extend your Application.java as public class App  extends SpringBootServletInitializer{..............}

Comment: yeah, but after reading few articles only war format supports this stuff. I want JAR to be created docker image and run on docker.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have maven plugin configured to be executable.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <executable>true</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And to run this war file in a docker container, just run it like it's just a jar file. In your Dockerfile, use your war's name:

```
ENTRYPOINT exec java -jar /my_project.war
```